# Sharepoint 2013 Embed Code box empty after saving

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I am trying to add some styling to a Sharepoint 2013 page using the Embed code feature.I add the CSS, it updates the link using the CSS. I hit insert on the embed code box and it still looks fine. As soon as I save the page, it refreshes and all of my code is removed and the box is empty except for the following:

```
<style unselectable="on">
</style>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sharepoint 2013 deleteing contents of <style> in embed code when saving](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21905139/sharepoint-2013-deleteing-contents-of-style-in-embed-code-when-saving)